# Why does my loop not iterate the whole length?

Tags: python, for-loop

This is the code:

```
r = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for x in r:
     print(r)
     r.pop(1)
```

When I `print(r)`, why does the print/loop stop after 5 iterations, and doesn't go the whole way?

Comment: you mutate the array while looping though it. What do you expect?

Comment: I thought it would iterate nine times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instruction `r.pop(1)` removes the element of the array at index 1. Since the array has 9 elements, and just because you print it before removing again, you see 5 iterations.

In details:

1. First iteration. `x` is 1, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` is printed, element `2` is removed
2. Second iteration. `x` is 3, `[1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` is printed, element `3` is removed
3. Third iteration. `x` is 5, `[1,4,5,6,7,8,9]` is printed, element `4` is removed
4. Fourth iteration. `x` is 7, `[1,5,6,7,8,9]` is printed, element `6` is removed
5. **Fifth iteration**. `x` is 9, `[1,6,7,8,9]` is printed, element `5` is removed
6. The loop ends because there's nothing more to iterate on.

Note how modifiying the array within the loop caused an unexpected sequence of items.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using `r.pop(1)` which removes in every iteration the element at index 1 of the list `r`, so you reach the list's end in the 5th iteration.

Note that in Python the indented block of a loop contains all commands that will be executed within that loop.

Comment: With a positive `1` argument, the `pop` call will be popping the second value in the list (initially `2`, but `3` the second time, etc.), not the last one. That would need `r.pop(-1)`.